# If two columns from different files equal, replace third column with awk

Tags: awk

I am looking for a way to replace a column in a file, if two `ID` columns match.
I have file `A.txt`

```
c   a   b   ID
1  0.01 5   1
2  0.1  6   2
3       2   3
```

and file `B.txt`

```
ID   a   b
1   10   15
2   20   16
3   30   12
4   40   14
```

The output im looking for is
file `A.txt`

```
ID a    b   
1  0.01 5   
2  0.1  6   
3   30  2
```

I can find with awk which `ID` columns from both files match

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a' B.txt A.txt
```

But how to add replacement. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Is there a typo in the last line of the A.txt example ? It has only 2 columns.

Comment: @HakanBaba no it is not, file A could have lines with less number of columns

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest ops, i can leave it out. sorry

Comment: do your files really have `id a c` line as header line?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ if(NR>1) a[$1]=$2; next }
     FNR>1 && $1 in a && NF<3{ f=$2; $2=a[$1]; $3=f }1' B.txt A.txt | column -t
```

- `if(NR>1) a[$1]=$2;` - capturing column values from file `B.txt` except the header line (`N>1`)
- `FNR>1 && $1 in a && NF<3` - if `ID`s match and some line from `A.txt` has less than 3 fields

---

The output:

```
ID  a     b
1   0.01  5
2   0.1   6
3   30    2
```

Comment: If `ID` column in file A is not first, how should i modify 2 part of the code?

Comment: @Pooh, you should know exactly where `ID` is located, cause it's a crucial field

Comment: it is actually `$1` from file B and `$3` from file A :(

Comment: @Pooh, in such cases you should extend your question describing additional conditions (posting new files)

Answer (score 0):

Adapted to your new data format

```
awk '
   # Load file b reference
   FNR==NR && NR > 1 {ColB[$1]=$2; next}

   # treat file A
   {
   # set missing field if know in file B (and not 1st line)
   if ( NF < 4 && ( $NF in ColB) && FNR > 1) $0 = $NF FS ColB[$NF] FS $2

   # print result (in any case)
   print
   }

   #order of file is mandatory' B.txt A.txt
```

Self documented.
Assume this is only the second field that is missing like in your sample